# Запятая внутри фразы "да так чтобы"

Tags: пунктуация

"Тёще полагалось готовиться к приходу зятя и гостей и потчевать их блинами и вкусными блюдами, да так чтобы никто не остался в обиде".

Нужна ли запятая перед "чтобы"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Тёще полагалось готовиться к приходу зятя и гостей и потчевать их блинами и вкусными блюдами, да так чтобы никто не остался в обиде.**

1) В этом предложении пауза перед ЧТОБЫ  может отсутствовать, и мне представляется, что написание без запятой возможно и даже правильно. Логическое выделение местоимение ***так*** удобно не во всех случаях.

2) Сочетание ***да так чтобы*** можно рассматривать как составной присоединительный союз со значением цели, куда входит местоимение ***так***. Расчленение этого союза возможно, но необязательно (как и других составных союзов).

3) Однако в Нацкорпусе нашлось только два примера без запятой, да и то в старых текстах. Вероятно, в современной орфографии такая запись считается устаревшей, что, как я думаю,  не совсем справедливо.

**Примеры:**

При прощаньи он подал мне 25-рублевую бумажку со словами: «Пожалуйста, передай от меня Володе, **да так чтобы** Любинька не знала». [А. А. Фет. Мои воспоминания / Часть II (1862-1889)]

[Акулина Гавриловна Красавина] **Да так чтобы** три дня кряду, а начинать с утра. [А. Н. Островский. За чем пойдешь, то и найдешь (Женитьба Бальзаминова) (1861)]

Answer (score 2):

*Тёще полагалось готовиться к приходу зятя и гостей и потчевать их блинами и вкусными блюдами, да так, чтобы никто не остался в обиде"*

(Потчевать как?) так, чтобы... фразовое ударение в присоединительной конструкции падает на ТАК, это указательное местоимение, к которому относится придаточное.